# How can I confirm that the DNS server I'm using is Microsoft-based?

Tags: windows, dns, active-directory

I'm having difficulty resolving AD-specific SRV records and would like to confirm whether or not the DNS server I'm using is Microsoft-based or something else (e.g. BIND).  Is there anyway to do this from the client side?  Unfortunately I don't have access to the DNS server itself and the internal IP is inconclusive.

Is there any way to find out from the client side?

Comment: Any reason you can't just call whoever administers the server and ask them?

Comment: @Eroen I have but the responses are delayed.  Was hoping for a quick method to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of

```
dig @nameserver version.bind txt chaos
nslookup -type=txt -class=chaos version.bind nameserver
```

If you get an answer, it is a version of BIND and might give a clue to the OS as well.

For obvious security reasons, this sort of facility is usually disabled.

There is also [fpdns](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-remotely-determine-dns-server-version.html), it may not have a Windows port but you could boot a Linux live CD.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try running nmap against it for a OS fingerprint?

There is also this project, but it suffers from the same issue-you have to install something.
http://code.google.com/p/fpdns/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback.  I'd prefer not to use NMAP.  If possible, I'd like to use the stock commands in Windows CL (windows server 2003/2008).